# jQuery animate up and down

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-animate

I'm building a webpage with a grid of images and when the user click on an image, a transparant layer slide up with an animation with some info about the image. This is working fine with the script that I have made below.

But I need to improve it because, when a user click on a second image, the prevoius transparant layer should slide back down and this is also working, but if the user click on the same layer, the animation will just slide up and then slide down. My question is if it's possible to improve my script to handle this.

My second question is that the script starts by slide down if any layer is already open, but does this affect all div tags or just the one that is opened? I guess there will be some performance issue if I have a big grid and the script slide down all layers despite that only one is visible!? Are my code OK or does it have any flaws that could be improved?

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".outer").click(function(){ 
    $(".inner").animate({height:'-=100%'},250);
    $(this).children(".inner").animate({height:'+=100%'},250);
});
});
```

HTML:

```
<div class='outer'>
<img src="image-1.png" class="click">
<div class='inner'><h1>Cover 1</h1></div>
</div>
<div class='outer'>
<img src="image-2.png" class="click">
<div class='inner'><h1>Cover 2</h1></div>
</div>
<div class='outer'>
<img src="image-3.png" class="click">
<div class='inner'><h1>Cover 3</h1></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.outer {
height: auto;
background: yellow;
position:relative;
width: 300px;
}

.outer img {
display: block;
}

.inner {
position: absolute;
bottom: 0;
height:0;
width: 100%;
background:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: Why not set an extra class and remove it when you click on another element? In that way you can set the transition on the extra class in CSS and keeps your HTML/CSS/JS clean(er).

Comment: @Roy Thanks for your comment! Then it will be pure CSS3 animation and not jQuery? Do you have time to make a simple answer to help me understand how you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a short example of what you want to achieve.

```
$(".box").removeClass('animate');
```

It first removes all the class `.animate` on every `.box`,

```
$(this).addClass('animate');
```

and after that, it sets that class only on the clicked element.

The `.animate` class can be anything, as long as it only contains the changes to the *normal* state of the element.

The transition can be altered very easily. Transition comes in very handy:

> The `transition` CSS property is a shorthand property for
>   `transition-property`, `transition-duration`, `transition-timing-function`,
>   and `transition-delay`. **It enables you to define the transition
>   between two states of an element.** Different states may be defined
>   using pseudo-classes like `:hover` or `:active` or dynamically set using
>   JavaScript.

Read more about it at [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/CSS/transition).

**Update**

```
    if ($(this).hasClass('animate')) {
        $(".box").removeClass('animate');
      } else {
        $(".box").removeClass('animate');
        $(this).addClass('animate');
      }
```

This will work for clicking another time.

```js
$(".box").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault;
  if ($(this).hasClass('animate')) {
    $(".box").removeClass('animate');
  } else {
    $(".box").removeClass('animate');
    $(this).addClass('animate');
  }
});
```

```css
.box {
  background: red;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
  top: 0;
  transition: margin-left .5s ease-in-out;
}
.animate {
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks Roy for your answer and code examples! I try to rebuild my code and add/remove class instead.

Comment: Would it also be possible to click and animate back on the same box?

Comment: Perhaps check if element has the class .animate and if true remove it?

Comment: Thanks! Now it's much better! :)